# Relative addressing in assembly

Tags: assembly, intel

I was wondering if I got this correctly:

As far as I know the syntax for relative addressing in x86 is like this:

```
base + index * scale + displacement
```

Now Igiven these assumptions:

```
int i //valuee in ecx 
int arr[256] //adress in esi
```

I want to load the following into eax:

arr[i + 10]

My first guess was:

```
mov eax, dword ptr[esi + ecx*4 + 10*4]
```

But I am unsure about the second multiplication since it would not fit the syntax mentioned above.

Also: What if the datatype of the index and the array are different. e.g:

```
short arr[i + 10]
```

What happens to the multiplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its always easier to break it down a bit, following your code:

- `esi` is  a pointer to `arr`
- `ecx` is `i`
- 10 * `sizeof(int)` = 40

so now we put it together:

`mov eax, dword ptr[esi + ecx* 4 + 40]`

thus your statement is correct. the second multiplication should be folded away by your assembler to a constant 40, if it doesn't then you'll need to calculate it by hand, but you'd need to test that on your assembler (or compiler if this is for inline assembly).

**Update**

You'd need to adjust the constants to the new element size, registers won't need to be changed though:
`mov eax, dword ptr[esi + ecx * 2 + 20]`

if this is done as inline assembler, then you can use the `sizeof` operator, to make life simpler, and have it folded away, certain assemblers may also allow a SIZEOF macro.

Comment: Ahhh dumb me. Totally forgot about optimizations like that ;-)

Comment: Hey I modified the original question to include a related topic. Can u comment on that too?

Comment: It should be either `esi+ecx*4+40` (32-bit) or `rsi+rcx*8+80` (64-bit), but not a mix of two. Also, I don't think you can nowadays find an assembler which doesn't do constant expression folding. Even assuming you do get one, it will definitely complain about "invalid" instruction when assembling it.

Comment: @Igor: It seems my math was a little off... however, `int`s are constant sized, so its 40 for 32 or 64 bit

Comment: Oops indeed, not sure why I decided it's longer on x64 :)